# Suppressing page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, page

I am using the `book` document class and am trying to suppress the page number print out in the ToC. I am using the commands

```
\phantomsection  
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{lipsum}
```

to include an entry in the ToC. This works fine for the entry but also prints the page number that I do not want.

Comment: `\usepackage{tocloft}` and `\cftpagenumbersoff` should work

Comment: Worked a charm, thx Chris!
And thx Martin for the edits re clarity!

Comment: Alright, but my name is Christian, not Chris ;-)

Comment: \thispagestyle{empty} will also work.  tocloft seems overkill.